# how to get last and first slide to make next and previous button active or disable accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created this slider code...

trying to get first and last slide to make next and previous button active or disable accordigly... can anyone help me to get it..

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.myslider-wrapper').each(function(){

    // thumbSlide
        var countSlider = $('.thumbSlide', this).length;
        if((".thumbSlide").length){        
            // Declare variables
            var totalImages = $(".thumbSlide > li", this).length, 
                imageWidth = $(".thumbSlide > li:first", this).outerWidth(true),
                totalWidth = imageWidth * totalImages,
                visibleImages = Math.round($(".thumbSlide-wrap", this).width() / imageWidth),
                visibleWidth = visibleImages * imageWidth,
                stopPosition = (visibleWidth - totalWidth/countSlider);  
            $(".thumbSlide", this).width(totalWidth+10);
        }
                $(".thumbSlide-prev", this).click(function(){
                var parentMove = $(this).parent().prev('.thumbSlide');
                if(parentMove.position().left < 0 && !$(".thumbSlide").is(":animated")){
                    parentMove.animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
                }               
                return false;
            });        
            $(".thumbSlide-next", this).click(function(){
                var parentMove = $(this).parent().prev('.thumbSlide');
                if(parentMove.position().left > stopPosition && !$(".thumbSlide").is(":animated")){
                    parentMove.animate({left : "-=" + imageWidth + "px"});                  
                }               
                return false;
            });        

     });

});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GLSqS/1/

many thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code little bit. Try the fiddle below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('.myslider-wrapper').each(function(){

// thumbSlide
    var countSlider = $('.thumbSlide', this).length;
    if((".thumbSlide").length){        
        // Declare variables
        var totalImages = $(".thumbSlide > li", this).length, 
            imageWidth = $(".thumbSlide > li:first", this).outerWidth(true),
            totalWidth = imageWidth * totalImages,
            visibleImages = Math.round($(".thumbSlide-wrap", this).width() / imageWidth),
            visibleWidth = visibleImages * imageWidth,
            stopPosition = (visibleWidth - totalWidth/countSlider);  
        $(".thumbSlide", this).width(totalWidth+10);
    }
            $(".thumbSlide-prev", this).click(function(){
            var parentMove = $(this).parent().prev('.thumbSlide');
            if(parentMove.position().left < 0 && !$(".thumbSlide").is(":animated")){
                parentMove.animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
                  $(this).parent().find('.disable').removeClass('disable');
            }else{
            $(this).parent().find('.thumbSlide-prev').addClass('disable');    
            }               
            return false;
        });        
        $(".thumbSlide-next", this).click(function(){
            var parentMove = $(this).parent().prev('.thumbSlide');
            if(parentMove.position().left > stopPosition && !$(".thumbSlide").is(":animated")){
                parentMove.animate({left : "-=" + imageWidth + "px"});
                 $(this).parent().find('.disable').removeClass('disable');
            }else{

            $(this).parent().find('.thumbSlide-next').addClass('disable');

            }               
            return false;
        });        

 });
```

});

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLSqS/8/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way, instead of class for next and previous use id for each slide to hide that particular one instead of all, i leave that to you,

I have done few changes to this code to show and hide, next and previous buttons:

```
if($('.thumbSlide li:first')){
        $('.thumbSlide-prev').hide();
                }
            $(".thumbSlide-prev", this).click(function(){
            var parentMove = $(this).parent().prev('.thumbSlide');
             $(".thumbSlide-next").show();   
            if(parentMove.position().left < 0 && !$(".thumbSlide").is(":animated")){
                parentMove.animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
            }else{
            $('.thumbSlide-prev').hide();
            }               
            return false;
        });        
        $(".thumbSlide-next", this).click(function(){
            var parentMove = $(this).parent().prev('.thumbSlide');
            //var parent=$(this).parent();
            $(".thumbSlide-prev").show();                
            if(parentMove.position().left > stopPosition && !$(".thumbSlide").is(":animated")){
                parentMove.animate({left : "-=" + imageWidth + "px"});                  
            }else{
            $(".thumbSlide-next").hide();
            }               
            return false;
        });
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLSqS/3/)

Comment: oops don't want to disable in all sliders :(

anyways...thanks